# Can a hosted application leverage the PhoneGap API?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

I am building a hosted mobile application so I can write once and deploy to many mobile platforms. My plan is to write a native application with a single screen that is a browser that navigates to my hosted application. Of course this is so our application is in the [App Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29), [Android Market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Market), etc.

Is it possible to use the [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap)  JavaScript so my hosted applications can use local APIs? For example, I would like to be able to upload pictures taken from the camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

More information: [PhoneGap: It's possible to use only the phonegap.js and it's functions only in a Website (doesn't want an App only a Webpage)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351201/phonegap-its-possible-to-use-only-the-phonegap-js-and-its-functions-only-in-a/3354644#3354644)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

No. You need to add pctures upload logic in each framework

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been answer it will also depend on your application store offering.  If you're intending to offer the app in the iPhone App Store, these kind of apps aren't permitted.  In the guidelines it states that apps that basically launch a browser or UIWebView will be rejected.

Additionally, you could always create the app as a "home screen" app, that runs without the chrome, etc on the iPhone.  Hope this helps.