# how does phonegap acess the giroscope, camera, geolocator?

Tags: cordova

Is phonegap just for designing an interface? As far as I've seen all applications are just like a normal html page, just that it is compiled into each phone OS separatelly.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate of the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351201/phonegap-its-possible-to-use-only-the-phonegap-js-and-its-functions-only-in-a).  Please take a look, the answer you seek is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap looks to me like some kind of browser shell, with enhanced native features accessible through Javascript and html5.

So opening a socket, or accessing a camera object in Javascript will instruct the app running on the phone to open the socket or access the camera, and pass the data back to Javscript.

This way you can code one app in html5 and Javascript, and it'll work on all phones since Phonegap provides the interface to the hardware through the phone's repective API's.